# Unable to send email with C# script in unity

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.6.1f1 and I want ot send an email from unity on the Click of a button, I do not have any email form to be filled in, the message body and Subject are aall hard coded. I am unable toi send the email. I have tried several times, also changed player settings APi to 2.0. I get the error IOException Connection closed when I use Send(mail)n method, but with SendAsync I dont get that message but the email is not sent to the recepient email. 
this is my script which I have attached to an ampty game object and then assigned that game object to a a button in the scene and selected the function name of the script for the Onclick event of the button.I get the message "Sending Email..."in my console but no email is sent.

```
        public void SendMail()
{


    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("receiver@mtc.edu.om");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from gmail";

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtpServer.Port = 465;

    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "senderpassword") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
      delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
      { return true; };
    smtpServer.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(MailDeliveryComplete);
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
    Debug.Log("success");
}

static void MailDeliveryComplete(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("Message \"{0}\".", e.UserState);

    if (e.Error != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Error sending email.");
    else if (e.Cancelled)
        Console.WriteLine("Sending of email cancelled.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
}
}
```

If I use port 587 Unity freezes. I have tried the SMTP server and port for yahoo mail also, and get the same error. Please help.

I have asked this question in Unity forum and was suggested to post the question here as it is more to do with the .Net framework. I am looking for help please as I am still not a pro in programming.

Comment: [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) is obsolete: _SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead_

Comment: [Gmail API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/gmail/v1) is also can be handy

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best idea to store password directly in your app. You should instead use a PHP script that will send email, and pass WWWForm from Unity using UnityWebRequest as POST.

The con of this solution is that you need a web hosting capable of running PHP, but there are lots of hosting services that are available for free.

Comment: What is the difference really? The information required to send a false e-mail is still available to anyone that has the code. I guess it does prevent a complete hijacking of the mailbox, but still not entirely secure.

Comment: You can just pass message and e-mail adress, your password and all credientials will be hidden in PHP script. You cannot just view content of PHP script so nobody will see the password or sender email adress

Comment: I meant that anyone would be able to send an email using the PHP script, but now that I think about it, that's probably acceptable.